# Debugging phonegap serve with phonegap developer

Tags: android, debugging, phonegap-developer-app

When i launch phonegap developer in my android phone after launching phonegap serve in the console, i don't have any log :

```
sudo phonegap serve
add to body class: platform-android
add to body class: platform-browser
[phonegap] starting app server...
[phonegap] listening on 192.168.1.81:3000
[phonegap] 
[phonegap] ctrl-c to stop the server
[phonegap] 
add to body class: platform-android
add to body class: platform-browser
[phonegap] 200 /__api__/appzip
```

However, if i launch the url http://192.168.1.81:3000 in a browser, i have the log :

```
sudo phonegap serve
add to body class: platform-android
add to body class: platform-browser
[phonegap] starting app server...
[phonegap] listening on 192.168.1.81:3000
[phonegap] 
[phonegap] ctrl-c to stop the server
[phonegap] 
add to body class: platform-android
add to body class: platform-browser
[phonegap] 200 /__api__/appzip
[phonegap] 200 /
[phonegap] 200 /css/ionic.app.css
[phonegap] 200 /lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js
[phonegap] 200 /lib/ngstorage/ngStorage.min.js
[phonegap] 200 /lib/angular-translate/angular-translate.min.js
[phonegap] 200 /cordova.js
[phonegap] 200 /lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js
[phonegap] 200 /lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js
...
[phonegap] [console.log] clean
[phonegap] 200 /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LN-GM2D&sid=1xRGqxTcx7-1oUGkAAAA
[phonegap] 200 /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LN-GM2H&sid=1xRGqxTcx7-1oUGkAAAA
[phonegap] [console.log] Init accountcontroller
[phonegap] 200 /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LN-GM4W&sid=1xRGqxTcx7-1oUGkAAAA
[phonegap] [console.log] Enter accountcontroller
```

How to get log from the phonegap developer app running ?

Note that i have the plugin cordova-plugin-console installed.

Comment: are you using eclipse or android studio...?

Comment: No, i just use sublimetext

Comment: you can get logcat either in `android studio` or `eclipse` so you can debug

Comment: When i launch 
    adb logcat
I have no more than
    - waiting for device -